# INotifyPropertyChanged: Should I Marshall Before or After Invoking?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have an application that modifies a data bound object in a background thread to avoid long running operations on the UI thread.

The data binding system in WPF marshalls changes from the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event to the UI thread automatically so this normally isn't a problem.

When I add an event handler that raises `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` to the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event I get a cross-thread `InvalidOperationException`.

Should I marshal back to the UI thread when I raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` or when I raise `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged`?

Both options have pros and cons but either way works.
What is considered best practise?

Here are the pros and cons of each so you understand why I'm asking:
[image: pros and cons]
These are just some off the top of my head. I'd like to know what's considered the best option and why. At the moment I think marshalling in the handler is a good option but it still doesn't sit well with me. Perhaps there's an option I've overlooked.

Comment: @peeyushsingh The referenced question is asking how to marshal invocation to a different thread. I already know how to do this. What I'm asking is best practise for managing the relationship between two events, one with special treatment from the framework.

Comment: hmm... did not read that properly.

Comment: "The data binding system in WPF marshalls changes from the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event to the UI thread automatically so this normally isn't a problem.". Untill it doesn't. On client's machine... [true story...]

Comment: The best practices: 1. Always use dispatcher. Don't care about the performance here, unless you do a really challenging stuff. 2. Introduce a service that injects IDispatcher (define this interface yourself). In prod it will inject Dispatcher, in tests it will simply execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming your code is something like

```
class MyCustomCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    // the rest of the ICommand interface members implemented    

    private void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, NotifyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In which case the `CanExecuteChanged` event of the command would be firing on the same background thread. Why this causes a cross-thread exception I don't know - you would have to provide more code to demonstrate the context in which these are being used, including how bindings are wired.

If you must marshall to the UI thread, I would marshall the raising of the `CanExecuteChanged` event because I'm assuming you want the remainder of your code on the background thread.

```
var dispatcher = GetADispatcherForMarshallingToUI();
dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty)));
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what my code looks like. Should I dispatch to the UI thread here or at the method that raises the event that calls this method?